# How to indent text between specific line numbers in vim?

Tags: indentation, shell

Let's say I want to indent everything between lines 40 and 60 (both lines included). One way of doing this is to go to line 40 and indent 21 lines:

```
:40
21>>
```

I am slightly bothered by having to enter two commands to do this. Is there a single command that lets me indent everything between two line numbers without having to compute the number of lines between the two lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the last command mentioned here [`:h shift-left-right`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#shift-left-right)

```
:[range]> {count} [flags]
```

So for your example

```
:40> 21
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to do any arithmetic in your head:

```
:40,60>
```

Comment: I didn't explain my requirement properly (edited now). What I want to do is to indent everything between two line numbers with one command and without having to calculate the number of lines between the two line numbers.

Comment: The command signature says [range] so put the line range there. I updated my answer.